# Send values with curl

Tags: curl, postman

I have this POSTMAN configuration for sending values to Spring end point:

[image]

Spring endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, value = "/v1/notification")
      public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotifications(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, Object> keyValuePairs) {

        LOGGER.debug("handleFormMessage");
        LOGGER.debug("keyValuePairs: {}", keyValuePairs);

        String unique_id = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("uniqueid"));
        String status = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("status"));
        String external_id = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("external_id"));
        String gateway = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("gateway"));
        String transaction_type = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("transaction_type"));

        try {

          System.out.println("!!!!!");
          System.out.println("!!!! unique_id " + unique_id);

              System.out.println("!!!!! Entered if(paymentTransaction.isPresent()) {");

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return new ResponseEntity<>("Please contact technical support!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
      }
```

Is there a way to send the same data with curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use postman's code button and select cURL:
[image]

[image]